# Weblogic scripting tool beginRepositorySession() fails

Tags: oracle, weblogic11g, wlst, rcu

I'm trying to use oracle's OWSM to secure my application. And i have scripts to create policies and authenticators. And when i try to run those script it fails at very first line, which is

```
 beginRepositorySession()
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
 "The MBean ,@ oracle.wsm:*,name=WSMDocumentManager,type=Repository was not found"
```

After going through some links i found that this error occur when i try to execute the wlst.sh from wrong location. But i'm executing it from the Oracle_common and still i'm getting this error.

Any idea.. why is this occurring? Is this some setup issue? or i need to do add some code before executing this **beginRepositorySession** ?

My wlst.sh location is

```
 $ORACLE_MIDDLEWARE/oracle_common/common/bin/wlst.sh
```

Thank You.

complete Exception trace :

```
wls:/myOWSM/serverConfig> beginRepositorySession()
Location changed to domainRuntime tree. This is a read-only tree with DomainMBean as the root. 
For more help, use help(domainRuntime)


Traceback (innermost last):
File "<console>", line 1, in ?
File "$ORACLE_MIDDLEWARE/oracle_common/common/wlst/wsmManage.py", line 172, in beginRepositorySession
File "$ORACLE_MIDDLEWARE/oracle_common/common/wlst/lib/ora_util.py", line 51, in raiseScriptingException
OracleScriptingException: The MBean oracle.wsm:*,name=WSMDocumentManager,type=Repository was not found.
```

Comment: Are you connecting to the instance before that line?

Comment: yes... and the connection is successful.. Even if i try this wlst cmd prompt. I'm getting same exception.

Comment: Is the server that the wsm-pm application is targeted to running and is it's status 'Active'?  I get the same MBean not found error when connected to an Admin server and the managed server hosting WSM isn't started .  I also get that error if I connect to a managed server where wsm-pm isn't targeted. Other than that, the session is started successfully running the wlst script from oracle_common/common/bin.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved this error after ,increasing the DB process value to 600,it was 150 and it was not enough for all the jobs.To see it you can use:

Oracle DB Sql:
"show parameter processes;"